# InnoDB has index problems when using COUNT() + WHERE

Tags: mysql, innodb

Recently, we switched from MyISAM to InnoDB. I tested the whole application and there are generally no problems except for one thing - using COUNT(*) in combination with 2 or more WHERE conditions.

So, here's the problem. The query below takes half a second which is not acceptable. After all InnoDB shouldn't be slower than MyISAM when using COUNT() + WHERE, but that's exactly what is happening here.

Both project_id and status_id are indexed columns. The table has 350K records.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM respondents WHERE project_id='366' AND status_id='42'
```

And here is what EXPLAIN says:

```
id  select_type     table        type         possible_keys         key                   key_len   ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE          respondents  index_merge  project_id,status_id  project_id,status_id  4,1       NULL    8343    Using intersect(project_id,status_id); Using where...
```

When I use only one condition after WHERE (either project_id='366' or status_id='42'), it works fine.
I'm thinking, this whole intersecting thing could be the root of the problem. But then what can I do about it? What do you think?

Comment: The answer, below, is good, but if you have just switched to InnoDB, you might also be experiencing performance issues because `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is too small, and you don't have enough room in the pool for enough pages of both indexes, necessitating pool evictions in the middle of the query.

Comment: See [Conversion tips](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) and [indexing cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index merge can be fixed by a compound index

```
ALTER TABLE respondents ADD KEY(project_id,status_id)
```

Assuming the data distribution is not very skewed,so this index will be useful.(the project_id='366' AND status_id='42' will not return more than 50% of rows)

Also make sure that your column types match the search.Are `project_id` and `status_id` really VARCHAR? If not remove the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just added a compound index and the query executed quite a bit faster, but is this really the only solution? I have to add a bunch of compound indexes whenever I have queries with more than one WHERE clause? If so, I'm going back to MyISAM (or perhaps Aria).

Comment: @Jeff If the WHERE conditons are with AND,yes you need a compound index.But queries which search only a single column can make use of this index if the column searched is the first column in the index.(project_id in this case)